# how to rename the link from the getUrl() function

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that I want to change the name of the url link. The script sends an email with a link to the document. However, I want the link to be "click here" instead of showing the link address. How do I go about doing this? Here is my code.

```
function sendDoc() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var url = ss.getUrl(); 
var body = "Hi Bo,\n\nHere are the weekly stats " + url;
var thanks = "\n\nThank You,\n   Chris";
var message = body + thanks; 

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the advanced arguments of the sendEmail function:

This should work:

```
function sendDoc() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var url = ss.getUrl(); 
var body = "Hi Bo,\n\nHere are the weekly stats " + url;
var thanks = "\n\nThank You,\n   Chris";
var message = body + thanks; 

MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {htmlBody: message.replace('link', '<a href="link">click here</a>')});
 }
```

Where **link** is the actual URL that you want to be emailed.

Here is a link to the documentation of the sendEMail function:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail

Comment: You will also have to use HTML tags to format your message (<BR>replaces \n\). See complete reference [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp)