# GmailApp.sendEmail() syntax for multiple options?

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to send emails with multiple hyperlinked text, line breaks and bolding. In addition to the [.sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)) documentation, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870490/how-to-rename-the-link-from-the-geturl-function) and answer, but I'm still confused. Here's what I'm doing:

```
function emailTest() {
var Link1 = "https://sites.google.com/a/****/item-shop" ; 
var Link2 = "https://sites.google.com/a/****/leader-board" ;
var name = "Adam";
var message = "Congratulations " + name.bold() + "!" + '\n' + '\n' + "check out this cool " + Link1 +  '\n' + '\n' +

          "and this cool " + Link2 +  '\n' + '\n' +
          "Keep up the good work!" + '\n' + "Mr. S.";

GmailApp.sendEmail ('fakename@gmail.com', "Congratulations!", message, 
                  {htmlBody: message.replace(Link1, '<a href="https://sites.google.com/a/****/item-shop">Item Shop</a>'),
                  htmlBody: message.replace(Link2, '<a href="https://sites.google.com/a/****/leader-board">LeaderBoard</a>')})
}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

bolding worked, and only 1 of the links, the line breaks did not happen.

any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: I ended up composing the whole message in html, using the method suggested in the answer: [here](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/54670/send-html-email-from-a-spreadsheet-using-a-different-alias)

Comment: also found this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30146530/sendemail-script-google-spreadsheets-multiple-options) useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried starting with the `http://` protocol?
Try this:

```
var link = "http://www.google.com";
var message = "Congratulations " + name[i] + "!" + '\n' + '\n' +

          "check out this cool " + link + + '\n' + '\n' +

          "Keep up the good work!" + '\n' + "Mr. S."
GmailApp.sendEmail(fakename@gmail.com, "Congratulations!", message,
{htmlBody: message.replace('link', '<a href="http://www.google.com">Website</a>')})
```

EDIT:
Try sepperating the links with the email send function, which also helps making it a little more readable. Try this (btw im not that familliar with google script but i am pretty sure this should work):

```
function emailTest() {
  var Link1 = "https://sites.google.com/a/****/item-shop" ; 
  var Link2 = "https://sites.google.com/a/****/leader-board" ;
  var name = "Adam";
  var message = "Congratulations " + name.bold() + "!" + '<br/>' + '<br/>' + "check out this cool " + Link1 +  '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
    "and this cool " + Link2 +  '<br/>' + '<br/>' +
    "Keep up the good work!" + '<br/>' + "Mr. S.";
  message = message.replace(Link1, '<a href="https://sites.google.com/a/****/item-shop">Item Shop</a>');
  message = message.replace(Link2, '<a href="https://sites.google.com/a/****/leader-board">LeaderBoard</a>');

  GmailApp.sendEmail ('fakename@gmail.com', "Congratulations!", message,  {htmlBody: message});
}
```

Comment: yes! that get's both the links to come out, but then the line breaks aren't coming out. when I replaced the `'\n'` with `'<br/>'` then everything works. If you want to edit your 2nd block of code, I'll check that off as the answer.  Thanks so much for your help.